# How to auto-scroll to unread messages on screen open?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-gifted-chat

I have a thread of chat messages and I want the screen to automatically scroll to the first unread message as soon as it loads, instead of having the list first scroll to the bottom and then to the message.

I tried the proposed solution from a [GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat/issues/938#issuecomment-754686709), but the issue is that the user can see the scroll to the bottom still happens, even when I set `animate: false`.

I achieved that by using `ScrollView`, however if a given thread has a lot of messages, the screen loads very slowly. I want to utilize FlatList's performance, but I can't get it to work the way I want it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the 'initialScrollIndex' attribute of FlatList (https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#initialscrollindex). If you encounter issues with the initial render, you can also consider using 'getItemLayout' or 'onScrollToIndexFailed' (check Flatlist Doc). Although it may involve a complex implementation, it is definitely worth it!

Comment: This works when the items have known height. I'm working on a chat app, so the message bubbles won't have always the same height. Unless I missed something?

Comment: You can use initialScrollIndex, to scroll through the first unread message. If you have a lot of unread messages it will have problems because flatlist wouldn't render all the elements. So you can use `onScrollToIndexFailed` to scroll until find the element (it will have animation)

Comment: If this isn't enough you can't play with your data. You can load the first unread message and when the user reaches the end `onEndReached` you can load the other messages.

Answer (score 0):

To automatically scroll to the first unread message in a FlatList component, use `initialScrollIndex` prop.
This prop allows you to set the index of the item that should be visible when the FlatList first renders.

example -

```
//assuming index is the index of the first unread message  
<FlatList 
    data={data}
    renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.text}</Text>}
    initialScrollIndex={index}
    />
```

`getItemLayout` prop can also be added in order to optimize the rendering performance of the FlatList by providing the height and offset for each item.